# Some Websites don't load after linux upgrade

Tags: internet

I just upgraded to `ubuntu 18.04` and I'm unable to visit some websites. It changes with time. A website I can visit now, I can't visit tomorrow. I also use openconnect and when it connects, no website loads at all.
The `ping` command receives respond packages, but neither firefox nor chrome load the websites.
I'm connected to my home network.

Comment: "Some websites"?

Comment: It's not all. some load, some don't. and it even varies from time to time.

Comment: The `ping` command receives respond packages, but neither firefox nor chrome load the websites.

Comment: Ever found a solution to the problem? I'm there now facing the same problem.

Comment: nope! It's still there. I just use a vpn or my tablet for those websites now. Sorry couldn't be of help.